# Find the youtube channel id for Google+ development or any other reason

Tags: youtube-api, google-plus

Find the channel id for a youtube channel in case you want to subscribe to it or for any other purpose.

Let's say you want to let the users subscribe to the client application's youtube channel by clicking subscribe. The user would have to sign in to Google+ and then run an api request to subscribe. So for this scenario you would need the channel id.
Please note that the new way of doing things is Google+ instead of GData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the following link and replace the username of that channel[foofightersVEVO with the username of that channel]

```
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=id&maxResults=1&q=foofightersVEVO&type=channel&_h=3&
```

execute the query and look at the api response:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&maxResults=1&q=foofightersVEVO&type=channel&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer


{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"2vd4g3cVsHAtTjJSdUMaBo1PBVE/6Ux-QcH6OQdn3t89j3y5z9RQhv0\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 161878,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"2vd4g3cVsHAtTjJSdUMaBo1PBVE/Q9-widOQXafayJk0l2DV9nrMYO0\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#channel",
    "channelId": "UCGRjJrpD2bmk9Ilq6nq80qg"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Note the channelId there. Hope this helps.